# How I can apply noise texture shape animation on a geometry?

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, compositing-nodes, volumetrics

i'm a begginer with geometry nodes.
I created this simple noise texture animation with geometry nodes. I was trying to put in on a desired shape. I didn't found the solution. I was trying to create volume and plug it instead of volume cube node, but idk, its not working also.

Can you help me? Is it possible to do this?
Here animation is working. I wanted to put this on Suzanne.

[image: noise_texture_shape_animation]

edit

I have actually no idea how to connect that animation to a tree.

[image]

Comment: In which way is it not working on Suzanne? At the moment it cannot work on Suzanne because you neither have Suzanne in there via _Object Info_ node nor have you added a _Geometry Nodes_ modifier on Suzanne to directly affect it - and even if you had, there is no _Group Input_ node in your setup to get the data from the base mesh which holds the modifier. It would be helpful to know what you actually tried to get it working on Suzanne. The screenshot shows nothing which could accomplish that task.

Comment: additionally you probably have to make sure that your Node Tree can handle your input type. Suzanne is a mesh. So instead of your `Volume Cube` node you probably want a `Mesh to Volume` node.

Comment: The issue with your second image is that *Mesh to Volume* - *Density* expects a single value (Float) for all voxels. So 3D texture is not accepted. Volume nodes in GN are quite limited at the moment so there is not a way to mix volumes here.  @GordonBrinkmann His first screen is showing working node-tree for *Volume Cube* node that is relevant input for mesh generation.

Comment: @vklidu Since she said in the question she wanted to "put it on a desired shape" and "wanted to put this on Suzanne" I was asking how this nodetree was supposed to obtain Suzanne as desired shape. If you put the GN modifier on Suzanne directly, she'll need a _Group Input_ node to get the shape into the nodetree. If the modifier is on a different object (like in the screenshot), she'll need an _Object Info_ node. Nothing of that is present. A _Volume Cube_ does not provide any mesh data from Suzanne.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your second image is that *Mesh to Volume* - *Density* expects a single value (*Float*) for all voxels. 3D texture is not accepted. Volume nodes in GN are quite limited at the moment so there is not a way to mix volumes here. You would have to somehow create a volumetric shader and export as VDB, that can be imported for GN.

Consider if for desired result could be enough to use *Noise Texture* for **Set Position** node before (or after) Volumes ... sure, the result is not the same.

[image]
[image]

... or if any Volume is needed at all.

As suggested by Gordon - It would be helpful to know what is your goal, because another approach can be to add *Empty Volume* object into your scene, assign **Volume to Mesh** modifier (Object > Suzane), assign **Volume Displace** modifier with *Noise* texture ... and than add GeoNode modifier with *Volume to Mesh* node.